# Pivotal server instance throws an error "Failed to start component" but works fine for same instance in different directory

Tags: java, spring, maven, server

Pivotal server instance throws an error "Failed to start component" but works fine for same instance in different directory.

> SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal
>   ContainerBase.addChild: start:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext

Comment: how do you run your application, I mean on eclipse or standalone tomcat?

Comment: on IDE (STS)...

Comment: Can follow the below steps:
Stop the server and then Clean Tomcat's work directory...
Navigate to servers tab -> select tomcat -> right click and click on clean tomcat work directory..